# how to put 2 div over each other?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have 2 div beside each other how can i make them over each other like in this picture below i'm using bootstrap ?

```
<div className="container mt-5">
        <h1 className="text-center">S.A.V</h1>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <img src="../../imgs/loading-logo.svg" alt="company" />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <p className="text-justify">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla arcu lorem, eleifend eget pharetra sit amet, tempor ut justo. Ut nec magna magna. Morbi suscipit vulputate ante. Aenean vel libero mattis, viverra ipsum quis, mollis eros. Cras vitae purus id velit volutpat posuere vel eget elit. Quisque convallis lectus vel lacus dictum, vel eleifend risus malesuada. Donec varius ut urna a gravida. Vestibulum convallis tristique nisi et iaculis. Aenean molestie nibh gravida ante pulvinar, in imperdiet lacus ultrices. Donec nec lacus tincidunt, lacinia nibh in, convallis diam
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: You probably can't do this with Bootstrap classes. Have you tried some custom CSS? You'll need to show us. It's a well-covered topic.

Comment: are you just wanting a bit of grey to bleed into the image column? if so, why not just stick a pseudo element with a grey background in the image column?

Comment: We'll need to see your CSS code...

Answer (score 1):

apply to the div father of the img {position:relative} and to img {position:absolute} then with top-right-left-bottom you can positionate the photo wherever you want... if the photo will not positionate over the other div apply a z-index value bigger than z-index of other div